# Application crash when loading map in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dictionary

I have map fragment its working fine on other devices but on samsung tab 2 it get crash when i open map fragment ,my log cat is as given below.

```
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547): Activity com.avion.mapdemo.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{417cecd0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-576,96} that was originally added here
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.avion.mapdemo.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{417cecd0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-576,96} that was originally added here
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:454)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:235)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:282)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at com.avion.mapdemo.MainActivity$GetPlaces.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:173)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at com.avion.mapdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
06-13 18:08:31.815: E/WindowManager(23547):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your code where you got this error?

Comment: Post your code here!!!

Comment: Post the preExecute method

Comment: What is at line `68`? and dismiss your `Dialog` in `onPostExecute(......)`

Answer (score 1):

Call `dismiss` method in OnPause of your Fragment.

I think even though you have moved out of fragment, the dialog is not dismissed.